# Inner Jordan measure of the set $A=\{(x,y): 0\leq x<1, 0<y<x^2\}\subseteq \Bbb R^2$.

Tags: measure-theory

Question is to find Iinner Jordan measure of the set $A=\{(x,y): 0\leq x<1, 0<y<x^2\}\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ i.e. $m_J(A)$. According to me set is Jordan measurable with Jordan measure as $\int_0^1x^2dx=1/3$ , so it is same as inner Jordan measure . Am I right ? Please comment .